# Identifier 'DoubleCenterException' has already been declared - Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I have a custom JS file in my Angular project. I have included it under `scripts` in `angular.json`

```
! function(r) {
    "use strict";
    var a = {
        init: () => {
            a.stickyHeader()
        },
        stickyHeader: () => {
            r(".navbar").length && new Headhesive(".navbar", {
                offset: 350,
                offsetSide: "top",
                classes: {
                    clone: "banner--clone fixed ",
                    stick: "banner--stick",
                    unstick: "banner--unstick"
                },
                onStick: function() {
                    r(r.SmartMenus.Bootstrap.init), r(".navbar:not(.fixed) .language-select .dropdown-menu").removeClass("show")
                },
                AonUnstick: function() {
                    r(".navbar.fixed .language-select .dropdown-menu").removeClass("show")
                }
            })
        },
    };
    a.init()
}(jQuery);
```

But when the angular app reloads, i get an error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'DoubleCenterException' has already been declared src\assets\site\js\theme.js:1
```

What could be the problem at line 1?

Comment: I think the problem is somewhere else in your code because an identifier represents the left side from dot.

Comment: @Reporter according to the console, the problem is on line 1 which is `! function(r) {`

Comment: A view at the Internet for this exception there several reasons for this message. A sidequestion: must `AonUnstick` changed to `onUnstick`?